# Which DLL contains the code of the code behind of a SVC-file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

I am making a tool which scans the drives of the current computer for applications made by our company. If it encounters one of our services (the SVC-file) it should also obtain te version of the code. To do so, it should find out which DLL is holding the code behind of the SVC-file.

The SVC-file only contains the name of the namespace and class, not the name of the DLL. The BIN-folder contain multiple DLL's, so which one could it be...?

In this case we cannot assume that the assemblies have the same name as the (root) namespace, so that is not any help.

The only way I can think of is opening all DLL's in a seperate AppDomain and check all the containing namespaces + classes.

Does someone know a quicker way?

Comment: The one containing the type as referred to in the .svc file. WCF will also scan assemblies for that namespace and type.

Comment: @CodeCast: So... you are saying that scanning ALL assemblies is the only solution?

Comment: Well, yes, the service type could reside in any assembly. That may sound inefficient, but the fact that you need this tool means you have no proper application lifecycle / release management, which is inefficient in itself to begin with.

Comment: About that lifecycle / release management, you are absolutely right. Our company realizes that and is trying to solve it. The first step: Get an overview of all the mess ;)

Comment: Good. No offense meant of course. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the software is now scanning all assemblies which could belong to the SVC-file. Creating seperate AppDomains to reflect each individual DLL is very slow. So I was thinking: "How do other programs deal with this problem?", so I took a look at [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

ILSpy uses [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) to reflect assemblies. It reads the assemblies on a binary level and does not create a seperate AppDamain. It even returns more information than normal reflection.

I downloaded this DLL and used it in my application and works perfectly.